# How to read and increment an Int variable of an outer class instance?

Tags: kotlin

Normal increment works in Kotlin just like in Java:

```
idCounter++
```

However, if idCounter is a variable of an outer class, how to apply the increment operator?

```
idCounter@OuterClass++
```

did not work, nor did

```
idCounter++@OuterClass
```

I've also fiddled with various variations of parenthesis without success.

Comment: Please post your classes so we can see the visibility modifiers of your property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to use `inner class` keyword for your inner class. Unlike Java, classes declared inside bodies of another class are `static class` by default. That's why you can't access your variable.

If you did use `inner class` and you need to use `idCounter` of outer class because you shadowed it in inner class, you should be able to access it using `this@OuterClass.idCounter`:

```
class OuterClass{
    var idCounter = 0
    var notShadowed = 0

    inner class InnerClass{
        var idCounter = 0

        fun foo(){
            idCounter++                  // modifying counter of InnerClass
            this@OuterClass.idCounter++  // modifying counter of OuterClass
            notShadowed ++
        }
    }
}
```